# How to change Canvas background color on click using button using tkinter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wanted to create a simple program to change the background colour of canvas in python using tkinter.

The should work like this:

suppose the current background colour of my canvas is red, the user clicks on a button on the canvas, then colour changes to blue, the user again clicks the button on the canvas, this time the colour changes  to yellow.

I need a simple program without classes if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice

colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']

root = Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")

button = Button(root, text="Button1", command=lambda: root.configure(bg=choice(colors)))

button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You are welcome!

```
from tkinter import * 
from random import choice

colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow']

top=Tk() 
top.title("Canvas Example 1") 

C=Canvas(top, bg="blue", height=250, width=400) 

line=C.create_line(10,10,250,250,fill="red") 
rect=C.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="red") 

button1 = Button(top, text = "Change color", anchor = W, command=lambda: C.configure(bg=choice(colors))) 
button1.configure(width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5", relief = FLAT) 

button1_window = C.create_window(10, 10, anchor=NW, window=button1) 

C.pack() 
top.mainloop()
```

You can also replace statement in `lambda` with a specific function.

```
def backgroundChanger(item):
    ...

button = Button(top, text='', command=lambda: backgroundChanger(C))
```

Comment: This is not the answer I was looking, I wanted it to be related more towards Canvas, as I already have different shapes such as rectangle, polygons and lines, I just want a button the canvas which changes the background color of canvas

Comment: I have not seen your code and I do not know exactly what you want. I wrote a button that changes the background of the element. Write a sample of your code in the question, and we'll see.

Comment: @VictorDorian: the solution for a canvas is precisely the same.

Comment: from tkinter import *
top=Tk()
top.title("Canvas Example 1")
C=Canvas(top, bg="blue", height=250, width=400)
line=C.create_line(10,10,250,250,fill="red")
rect=C.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="red")                   
button1 = Button(top, text = "Change color", anchor = W)
button1.configure(width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5", relief = FLAT)
button1_window = canvas1.create_window(10, 10, anchor=NW, window=button1)    
C.pack()
top.mainloop()

Comment: Now i know how to add button on the canvas button haven't defined any command to it as  the command will call a function that will help me change the background color.  I am asking the code for that particular function